# Theos SDK 3.2 and iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, sdk, theos

okay two questions,
1. how do you force theos to use the 3.2 sdk (is it as simple replacing the 2.0 sdk with the 3.2 one? and
2. how would you develop a simple gui application for iPad using the sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't figured this out yet, and for anyone else looking for this information the solution is quite simple.
In your Info.plist add the "UIDeviceFamily" key and an array with integer's for the devices you wish to support, 1 for iPhone/iTouch and 2 for iPad.
Example.

```
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
```

This makes the app universal.

More Info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

Install **BigBoss Recommended Tools** from **Cydia**. Download the `libgcc` package from http://apt.saurik.com/cydia/debs/libgcc_4.2-20080410-1-6_iphoneos-arm.deb and then install it. After that install the **GNU C Compiler** also from **Cydia**. Add the repo `ininjas.com/repo/` and install **class-dump-z**, **Perl iPhone Source** and **Mobile Terminal** from **Cydia**. Fire up terminal and run `su`, enter root password (`alpine` by default) and then finally`installtheos3`. After that let it do its magic then run $THEOS/bin/nic.pl to get started!

Comment: yeah ive already done all that and everything compiles fine, but its there a way to get the final product the "app" to display in fullscreen iPad mode. Also is the way to put it into fullscreen "iPad" mode to force theos to use sdk 3.2?